# Oracle 18c XE installation failure - [FATAL] Error while cataloging RMAN Backups on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: database, oracle, tns, rman

Prepare for db operation
7% complete
Copying database files
8% complete
[WARNING] ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

29% complete
100% complete
[FATAL] Error while cataloging RMAN Backups
7% complete
0% complete
Look at the log file "/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/XE/XE3.log" for further details.

Database configuration failed. Check logs under '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca'.